leafmap with streamlit cannot get a drawn feature
I'm able to show a map in streamlit, draw a shape, but don't see any working way of catching a drawn shape for processing. I'm using leafmap.foliumap, as other backends didn't work with streamlit. I run it locally on Win. I also display geodataframe and want to use the drawn shape to filter gdf raws. All functions I tried either don't work or don't exist in leafmap.foliumap or I don't know how to invoke them, as they require some streamlit object (st_component) as argument, eg st_last_draw.
import streamlit as st
import leafmap.foliumap as leafmap

st.title("Map page")
m = leafmap.Map(center=[52.2, 21.0], zoom=13)
output = m.to_streamlit(width=700, height=500)

How can I catch the shape using this library?
